# Boolean algebras- question

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, universal-algebra

Let B be a Boolean algebra. Let a,b be elements of the universe of B such that $\neg a$ < 1 and b < 1 and $(\neg a \vee b)= 1$. Is it always the case that $a \leq b$? If not could you provide a counterexample?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I know that it holds for the diamond-shaped Boolean algebra B={1,x,y,0}. However, I am not sure how to generalize it.

Comment: By definition, $a \leq b$ iff $a = a \wedge b$. Now use $a = a \wedge 1$ and the identity in your post.

Comment: @Rushy’s hint shows the way. You’ll also need to use the fact that Boolean algebras are distributive.

Comment: @Rushy Thanks for the Hint, I think I would have got there but it would have taken a while! Still thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\neg a \vee b = 1$ implies $a \leq b$ in any Boolean algebra. This does not even use the additional assumptions that $\neg a < 1$ and $b < 1$. To see this, we can follow Rushy's suggestion in the comments:
$$
a = 1 \wedge a = (\neg a \vee b) \wedge a = (\neg a \wedge a) \vee (a \wedge b) = 0 \vee (a \wedge b) = a \wedge b.
$$
So because $a = a \wedge b$ we conclude that indeed $a \leq b$.

There is actually a good intuitive explanation for this as well. If we think about propositional logic then the statement "$a$ implies $b$", usually written as $a \to b$, is logically equivalent to $\neg a \vee b$. We can view a Boolean algebra as a set of truth values. Obviously $\wedge$ and $\vee$ then represent the 'and' and 'or' operations respectively, while $1$ and $0$ give us 'true' and 'false'. The interpretation of $a \leq b$ is "$a$ implies $b$". So what we have just seen is that also in Boolean algebras we have that when $\neg a \vee b$ is true then "$a$ implies $b$" (i.e. $a \leq b$).

In fact, the converse is also true: if $a \leq b$ then $\neg a \vee b = 1$. This follows because $a \leq b$ implies $\neg b \leq \neg a$ and since $\neg b \vee b = 1$ we then have by monotonicity of $\vee$ that indeed $\neg a \vee b = 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I had in mind, whether it would be possible to substitute the Boolean conditional by $\leq$. I was also wondering about the other direction, so thanks a loooot!

Comment: does the same hold for any Heyting algebra, so $a \Rightarrow b = 1$ iff  $a \leq b$ ? (I know that it holds at least for any linear Heyting algebra)

Comment: Yes, but that would probably be worth opening a new question for (if it has not been asked before). So you can give the definitions you're working with (multiple are possible for Heyting implication) and so you can get a more detailed answer.